# WP_QUERY tax_query not working

Tags: wp-query

```
$query_args = array(
        'cat' => $lesson_id,
        'meta_value' => $lesson_type,
        'post__not_in' => array($current_post_id),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'series',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $series_id,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )       
        )

    );
```

I'm trying to exclude posts tagged with a series id in the series custom taxonomy, but it's not working. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

The `'field' => 'id'` is not valid.

Try `'field' => 'term_id'` instead.